# Camera 2 preview freezes when I uses YUV_420_888 Image Reader as a target surface

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2

I'm working on an application that has requirements to detect objects and faces in a real-time camera feed. for this, I'm using MLkit. I have successfully implemented it object detection part with the back-facing camera with no issue. ML kit recommends using `YUV_420_888` with the smallest size possible to have better results. I am using Camera 2 API and here's my code for setting up `ImageReader` for processing.

```
class SelfieCaptureFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_selfie_capture) {

    protected lateinit var characteristics: CameraCharacteristics
    protected lateinit var camera: CameraDevice
    protected lateinit var session: CameraCaptureSession
    protected lateinit var requestPermissionLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<String>
    protected lateinit var captureImageReader: ImageReader
    protected lateinit var analyzeImageReader: ImageReader
    
    /** [HandlerThread] and [Handler] where all camera operations run */
    private val cameraThread = HandlerThread("CameraThread").apply { start() }
    private val cameraHandler = Handler(cameraThread.looper)

    /** [HandlerThread] and [Handler] where all camera still image capturing operations run */
    private val captureImageReaderThread = HandlerThread("captureImageReaderThread").apply { start() }
    private val captureImageReaderHandler = Handler(captureImageReaderThread.looper)

    private val analyzeImageReaderThread = HandlerThread("imageReaderThread").apply { start() }
    private val analyzeImageReaderHandler = Handler(analyzeImageReaderThread.looper)

    companion object {
        /** Maximum number of images that will be held in the reader's buffer */
        const val IMAGE_BUFFER_SIZE: Int = 3
    }

    private fun configureCamera(selectedCameraId: String) {

        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {

            camera = openCamera(cameraManager, selectedCameraId, cameraHandler)

            val previewFraction = DisplayUtils
                .asFraction(previewSize!!.width.toLong(), previewSize!!.height.toLong())

            // Initialize an image reader which will be used to capture still photos
            captureSize = characteristics.get(
                CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)!!
                .getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)
                .filter { DisplayUtils.asFraction(it.width.toLong(),it.height.toLong()) == previewFraction }
                .sortedBy { it.height * it.width}
                .reversed()
                .first()

            analyzeImageSize = characteristics
                .get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)!!
                .getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)
                .filter { DisplayUtils.asFraction(it.width.toLong(), it.height.toLong()) == previewFraction }
                .sortedBy { it.height * it.width}
                .first()

            if (captureSize != null) {

                captureImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
                    captureSize!!.width, captureSize!!.height, ImageFormat.JPEG, IMAGE_BUFFER_SIZE
                )

                analyzeImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
                    analyzeImageSize!!.width,
                    analyzeImageSize!!.height,
                    ImageFormat.YUV_420_888,
                    IMAGE_BUFFER_SIZE)

                Log.d(TAG, "Selected capture size: $captureSize")
                Log.d(TAG, "Selected image analyze size: $analyzeImageSize")

                val targets = listOf(
                    binding.cameraSurfaceView.holder.surface,
                    captureImageReader.surface,
                    analyzeImageReader.surface
                )

                session = createCaptureSession(camera, targets, cameraHandler)

                val captureBuilder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
                captureBuilder.set(
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE
                )
                captureBuilder.addTarget(binding.cameraSurfaceView.holder.surface)
                captureBuilder.addTarget(analyzeImageReader.surface)

                session.setRepeatingRequest(captureBuilder.build(), null, cameraHandler)

              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is identical to what I'm using in the back-facing camera to set up the image reader for the object detection part. I have not yet Implemented any logic related to Image processing to detect faces in the camera steam. Error is in the line where I set up the target. `captureBuilder.addTarget(analyzeImageReader.surface)` If I comment that line camera preview works fine. I get the following error and warning in logcat over and over when the camera preview freezes.

```
W/libc: Unable to set property "debug.sf.dequeuebuffer" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
E/BufferQueueProducer: [ImageReader-256x144f23m3-23007-3](id:59df00000003,api:4,p:4806,c:23007) waitForFreeSlotThenRelock: timeout
```

I can't understand why it's not working in the front-facing camera. analyze image size return from the `analyzeImageReader` is 256x144 which is not a big resolution either plus it's the smallest out of all the supported sizes for the format of `YUV_420_888`. Any Help will be highly appreciated. I thought I have figured it out all when I implemented objected detection part. this was a very unexpected issue.

**Edit**: I'm still stuck with this issue so I have set up a small [project](https://github.com/ChathuragaShan/FrontCameraImageReaderIssue) to showcase the whole picture. Please check the [repo](https://github.com/ChathuragaShan/FrontCameraImageReaderIssue) and help me find a solution.

Comment: `analyzeImageSize` is derived for JPEG, but used to create YUV_420_888 surface. I am not sure this is the root cause of your problem, but it's worth checking. If you don't intend to capture JPEG from this camera, you can drop the `captureImageReader` altogether. But if you do, make sure that both readers have the same (width, height).

Comment: Hi, I noticed It and I changed It. This was because I was trying with a different format to check if it works and forgot to change it back before putting the code here. I'm getting the same issue with setting Image type to  YUV_420_888 in both places.

Comment: Also, this could be a bug of the specific device model.

Comment: About using different sizes for `ImageReaders`. I do need to capture the image so I need to use captureBuilder. I can't use 2 Image readers of the same size since MLkit face detection requires to use small size but I need to capture an image in full size. I did use it the same way in a Front-facing camera with object detection and it worked. So is there any possibility to not work it in font facing camera because `ImageReaders` are different sizes ?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps: I had a similar issue with one phone model (Samsung A50). I managed to solve it by changing this:

```
captureImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null)
```

To:

```
captureImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->
            reader.acquireLatestImage().close()
        },imageReaderHandler)
```

Comment: I had listener already set, but app did crash before `close()` was ever called, hence the logs (`waitForFreeSlotThenRelock: timeout`) have nothing to do with the actual crash.