# Clear Image Reader Buffer in CameraX API

Tags: android, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I am using CameraX API and its ImageAnalysis to analyze each frame. Processing of frames takes some time and imageReader buffer gets filled resulting in this error -

`[ImageReader-256x144f23m4-11920-0](id:2e9000000000,api:4,p:651,c:11920) waitForFreeSlotThenRelock: timeout`

How can I clear the Image Reader when it gets filled up and carry on processing frames at the same speed.

Here is my analyze Function

```
        @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
        override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
            val image = imageProxy.image

            if (image != null) {
                val inputImage =
                    InputImage.fromMediaImage(image, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)
                processImage(inputImage, imageProxy)
            }else {
                imageProxy.close()
            }
        }
```

And ProcessImage Function

```
 @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
        private fun processImage(image: InputImage, imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
            poseDetector.process(image).addOnSuccessListener { results ->
                posesfromMLKit = getPoseCoordinate(results, imageProxy)
                if (isFullDetectionStarted) {
                    getPoints(posesfromMLKit)
                }
                try {
                    // Convert Image to BitMap
                    val yBuffer = imageProxy.image!!.planes[0].buffer // Y
                    val vuBuffer = imageProxy.image!!.planes[2].buffer // VU

                    val ySize = yBuffer.remaining()
                    val vuSize = vuBuffer.remaining()

                    val nv21 = ByteArray(ySize + vuSize)

                    yBuffer.get(nv21, 0, ySize)
                    vuBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vuSize)

                    val yuvImage =
                        YuvImage(nv21, ImageFormat.NV21, image!!.width, image!!.height, null)
                    val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                    yuvImage.compressToJpeg(Rect(0, 0, yuvImage.width, yuvImage.height), 50, out)
                    val imageBytes = out.toByteArray()
                    base64EncodedFrame = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageBytes).toString()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    imageProxy.close()
                }
                frameratePerSecond++
                imageProxy.close()
            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                imageProxy.close()
            }.addOnCompleteListener {
                imageProxy.close()
//                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
//                        delay(100)
//                        imageProxy.close()
//                    }
            }.addOnCanceledListener {
                imageProxy.close()
            }
        }
```

I tried dropping some frames when processImage function is processing 1 frame. But it resulted in Slow Processing somehow.

but that solved the error, yet it is not a good approach for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ImageReader` queue does not get filled up with the default `ImageAnalysis` configs. e.g. the [STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis#STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST()) mode. With this mode, CameraX keeps dropping incoming frames until the current frame is closed. Could you post your `ImageAnalysis` configuration?

The resolution is `256x144` which is uncommon for camera. My guess is that it's the queue in MLKit gets filled up.

Comment: Basically, logs (`waitForFreeSlotThenRelock: timeout`) happen if `Image` is never closed (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67145610/camera-2-preview-freezes-when-i-uses-yuv-420-888-image-reader-as-a-target-surfac#comment135468493_68248540).

Answer (score 0):

```
val options = PoseDetectorOptions.Builder()
.setDetectorMode(PoseDetectorOptions.STREAM_MODE)
.build()
```

Would ensure a faster processing hence faster results. Make sure you have set it. Read more here: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/pose-detection/android?authuser=1#tips_to_improve_performance

Also, make sure the you `setBackpressureStrategy` to `STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST`. Read more here: https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/analyze#operating-modes